# To count number of rows in a table if the rows were created after the DOM loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I create rows after the DOM loaded, but I want to know how to count number of rows for eliminate the last.

I have this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">//Procesamiento del formulario.
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var cuentaTr = $('#elementos >tbody >tr').length - 1; //Cuenta el número de filas que tiene la tabla originalmente, es 1.
        $('#agregar').click(function(){ //Clic en el botón que agrega nueva fila.
            cuentaTr++; //Es el número de fila que le corresponde a cada una que se crea.
            var nume = $('#elementos >tbody >tr >td').length; //Obtener el número de celdas
            var capa = document.getElementById("elementos"); //Obtener el elemento con el id elementos
            var tr = ("tr"); //Crear una tag tr
            capa.appendChild(tr); //Agregar la tag al elemento con id elementos.

            var nuevaLetra = "A"; //La variable con la que se le asigna una letra a cada columna.
            for (var i = 1; i <= nume; i++) {
                    $('<td><input type="text" class="prueba" id="'+nuevaLetra+cuentaTr+'" name="columna'+nuevaLetra+cuentaTr+'" required/></td>').appendTo('#elementos'); //Creación de nuevo input. THIS IS THE IMPORTANT!
                    var ASCII = nuevaLetra.charCodeAt(); //Obtener código ASCII
                    var aumento = ((ASCII+1 >= 65 && ASCII+1 <= 90) || (ASCII+1 >= 97 && ASCII+1 <= 122)) ? ASCII+1 : ASCII; //Incremenar la letra
                    var nuevaLetra = String.fromCharCode(aumento); //Tranformar el código a letra.
            };


            if (cuentaTr == 2){
                $('<button type="button" id="eliminame">-</button>').insertAfter('#agregar'); //Creación del botón de eliminación de filas
                };
            });

        $(document).on('click', '#eliminame', function(){ //Función que elimina las filas HERE IS MY DUDE.  
            $('#elementos tbody tr:last').remove(); //I WANT TO REMOVE THE LAST ROW. THIS CODE ELIMINATE ONLY THE ROWS CREATE WHEN DOM LOADED.
            cuentaTr--;
            if (cuentaTr == 1) {
                $(this).remove();
            };
            });



        });


 </script>
```

What I can to do?

Thank you!
I'm sorry for my English. I can't speak English well.

Comment: one problem is you can't append `<td>` to `<table>` without a parent `<tr>`. This may be causing the problem

Comment: var nume = $('#elementos >tbody >tr >td').length; //Obtener el número de celdas
            var capa = document.getElementById("elementos"); //Obtener el elemento con el id elementos
            var tr = ("tr"); //Crear una tag tr
            capa.appendChild(tr); //Agregar la tag al elemento con id elementos.

Here I create a parent <tr>

Comment: you were creating it but appending the `<td>` to `#elementos` here `.appendTo('#elementos')`...not to the `tr` you create

Comment: then do this  `.appendTo('#elementos tr:last')` so `<td>` gets into new row you just appended

Comment: So, .appendTo(tr).
Ok, I'm sorry, I have a error there xd. But the principal problem isn't there, is down.

Comment: Ok thank you so much, but my principal problem is there yet :/

Comment: Oh Thank you!! $('#elementos tbody tr:last').remove(); is really $('#elementos tr:last').remove(); 

My problem finished! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are some problems on how the tr is appended to the table, try

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var cuentaTr = $('#elementos >tbody >tr').length - 1; //Cuenta el número de filas que tiene la tabla originalmente, es 1.
     $('#agregar').click(function () { //Clic en el botón que agrega nueva fila.
         cuentaTr++; //Es el número de fila que le corresponde a cada una que se crea.
         var nume = $('#elementos >tbody >tr:first >td').length; //Obtener el número de celdas
         var capa = $("#elementos"); //Obtener el elemento con el id elementos
         var tr =  $('#tr').appendChild(tr); //Agregar la tag al elemento con id elementos.

         var nuevaLetra = "A"; //La variable con la que se le asigna una letra a cada columna.
         for (var i = 1; i <= nume; i++) {
             $('<td><input type="text" class="prueba" id="' + nuevaLetra + cuentaTr + '" name="columna' + nuevaLetra + cuentaTr + '" required/></td>').appendTo(tr); //Creación de nuevo input. THIS IS THE IMPORTANT!
             var ASCII = nuevaLetra.charCodeAt(); //Obtener código ASCII
             var aumento = ((ASCII + 1 >= 65 && ASCII + 1 <= 90) || (ASCII + 1 >= 97 && ASCII + 1 <= 122)) ? ASCII + 1 : ASCII; //Incremenar la letra
             var nuevaLetra = String.fromCharCode(aumento); //Tranformar el código a letra.
         };


         if (cuentaTr == 2) {
             $('<button type="button" id="eliminame">-</button>').insertAfter('#agregar'); //Creación del botón de eliminación de filas
         };
     });

     $(document).on('click', '#eliminame', function () { //Función que elimina las filas HERE IS MY DUDE.  
         $('#elementos tbody tr:last').remove(); //I WANT TO REMOVE THE LAST ROW. THIS CODE ELIMINATE ONLY THE ROWS CREATE WHEN DOM LOADED.
         cuentaTr--;
         if (cuentaTr == 1) {
             $(this).remove();
         };
     });



 });
```

Comment: Hi!
var tr =  $('#tr').appendChild(tr);
How .appendChild has tr if var tr is create in that moment?

Answer (score 0):

`var cuentaTr = $('#elementos >tbody >tr').length - 1;` (already in your code) should give you the number of rows (minus one). Maybe make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can debug what's going on?

Comment: It give me the number of tr than the table has actually(Is 2 always. One tr>th and One tr>td's). I put -1 because 1 tr is for th and the second tr is for td's. I don't want than eliminate my th's. Only mi tr that it has 8 td's.
I know that there isn't the problem. The problem is in $(document).on('click', '#eliminame', function ().